# Como faço para arrumar essa tag em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

***Estou finalizando um código em JavaScript de um Balanço Familiar de custos,
No entanto, quando vou tentar passar a variável para imprimir na tela (que seria a ${totalBalanço} e a $total.Tofixed(2)}R$, aparentemente não esta funcionando.
Tentei alterar as aspas, tentei alterar colocando apostrofe, mas nada altera a cor desse atributo no meu VSCode.***

[image: Foto do Código]

[image: No momento de Imprimir na tela]

[image: O que eu gostaria que acontecesse.]
O que devo fazer para conseguir imprimir os resultados na tela?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está tentando utilizar o template literals que é esse símbolo -> ${}

No seu caso, você está utilizando aspas dupla. Assim:

`"String com aspas duplas"`

Mas só é possível utilizar o template literals em strings atribuídas com a crase. Ex:

`` `Aqui é uma string com crase` ``

`` `Outra string com crase e com um template literal -> ${algumaVariavel}` ``

Comment: Agradeço a resposta, coloquei Crase e funcionou!

Answer (score -1):

Já tentou utilizar literais de modelo(Template String)? talvez seja a solução que você procura.
[Template String](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
let a = 5; b = 10;
console.log(`Sum of ${a} and ${b} is ${a + b}`);
```